# UPnP in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: upnp

I use qBittorrent and a Tenda R502 router. I enabled UPnP in the router and also in qBittorrent but I still don't have direct incoming connections (there is a little yellow sign, which must be green).

Is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS accepting UPnP or do I need to install something?

Thanks

Epsi

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to install 
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/upnp-inspector/
and see if you get anything.

Piotras